# Pegar id do botao clicado quando clicar em outro botão

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Preciso fazer com que quando o usuario clicar no botão de opções, ele guarde esse valor do id e quando clicar em outro botao "confirmar" ele mostre o id do primeiro botao clicado.

Tentei fazer com localstorage, mas ele acaba mostrando todos os id's de todos os botoes.

```
        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="1">EXCEDEU O HORARIO</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="2">CLIENTE REALIZOU</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="3">ERRO DE ENTREGA</button>
      </div>
    </div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success but_pag_nao" id="confirm_ob" onClick="ok();">CONFIRMAR</button>
```

Comment: Por que não usa o `input type="radio"` para isso? Outra possibilidade é o uso do [button group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/button-group/)

Comment: É que eu preciso que seja do jeito que informei :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solução usando apenas javascript**

```js
window.idBotaoClicado =0;

function botaoClicado(e){
  window.idBotaoClicado= e
 }

function ok(){
  alert(window.idBotaoClicado)
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="1" onclick="botaoClicado(this.id)">EXCEDEU O HORARIO</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="2" onclick="botaoClicado(this.id)">CLIENTE REALIZOU</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="3" onclick="botaoClicado(this.id)">ERRO DE ENTREGA</button>
      </div>
    </div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success but_pag_nao" id="confirm_ob" onClick="ok();">CONFIRMAR</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que seria mais fácil se vc mostrasse o que está usando, se é JQuery, ou coisas do tipo... Bem usando o JS puro podemos fazer assim:

```js
var primeiroBtn = "";

function ok(elemento){
  primeiroBtn = elemento.id;
}

function cancel(){
  window.alert(primeiroBtn);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="ok(this);" id="testeBTN">OK btn</button>
<button onClick="cancel();">Cancel bnt</button>
```